# C++17 no matching function for call to reduce error

Tags: c++, c++17

This code is from the book *C++17 Standard Library Quick Reference* by Apress:

```cpp
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  vector vec {4,2,5,1,3,6};
  int sum = reduce( begin(vec), end(vec));
}
```

When I compile it with `g++-9.2` using the option `-std=c++17` (or `-std=gnu++2a`) on **Windows 7**, I get:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'reduce(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::iterator, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::iterator)'
```

What's wrong with this code? Thank you.

Comment: I think you need g++ 10 (experimental) but I am not sure, never tried it.

Comment: What is `begin`? or `end`? Usually these are always called as member functions , such as `vec.begin()` and `vec.end()`

Comment: @JoshWeinstein • introduced with C++11, [std::begin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin).

Comment: @JoshWeinstein these are `std::begin` and `std::end`. One should prefer then in generic contexts, since they also work for C-style arrays.

Comment: @JoshWeinstein those are part of `std` and will usually defer to the member functions.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/ayzmzs/is_stdreduce_implemented_in_gcc_or_clang/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) and as another comment mentioned you should use newer version of gcc (experimental one). Try [here](https://godbolt.org/z/TExitc)

Comment: This code compiles w/o error with trunk clang and libc++.

Comment: @JoshWeinstein I don't know in detail what those functions are, they were just there at the page number 133 in the book. I've just tried the code and it constantly gave this error.

Comment: @MarshallClow Clang sounds like a macOS thing not a Windows thing and I'm using Windows 7 (just edited the post) Besides, I think it would be an overkill to switch to clang just to use the reduce function.

Comment: It's almost certainly a libc++ vs. libstdc++ thing.

Comment: If you plug your code into Compiler explorer, and choose "clang 9.0", it will fail to compile. But if you add `-stdlib=libc++` to the compiler options, it does compile. Definitely a libc++ vs. libstdc++ difference.

Comment: @MarshallClow I don't prefer clang. It's best to stick to gcc.

Comment: @DimChtz It turns out you're right because `gcc-10.0.0` is able to compile this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another comment already pointed out, I have tried compiling your code with `x86-64 gcc (contracts)` version which is, I suppose, experimental version of gcc compiler and the compilation was successful. Try it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/TExitc).

Also, I run into an interesting post on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/ayzmzs/is_stdreduce_implemented_in_gcc_or_clang/) with the same topic as the one we are discussing here.

**EDIT**

As OP posted in the comment below, `gcc-10.0.0` compiles code from the question successfully.

Comment: It looks like `gcc-10.0.0` is able to compile this code.